# How do I answer to a screen capture dialog in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium

A website I am trying to automate with puppeteer has a screen record feature with screen capture in chrome. I've done everything so far except for being able to answer to that dialog.

I've tried using keyboard inputs such as Tab and Enter.

[image: Here's an example I've found]

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: @T.Demirer Sadly never did and gave up on the project entirely

Comment: Hi bro, I have found the solution. It was annoyingly easy. I can share it with you if you want.

Comment: @T.Demirer please post it as an answer to the question, maybe someone will need the help in the future